# Unable to install any Linux distribution on my PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, fedora

I wanted to install Linux in parallel to my current Windows 10 installation on my main desktop. I've installed different variants of Linux on different PCs and VMs dozens of times now, but this time I simply can't get it to work no matter what I do.

The PC is a bit older Intel i5-2500K on an ASUS P8Z68-V LX mainboard, with a Geforce 970 GTX.

I've varied the following aspects of the installation, but I never get further than the start of the Linux boot process:

- different USB drives (2.0 and 3.0)
- different USB ports (all 2.0)
- Fedora 26 and Ubuntu 17.04
- booting in UEFI or legacy mode
- verifying the Fedora USB drive before installing

There is no DVD drive attached to the PC, so I can't try that.

Shortly after booting from the USB drive I always end up with something looking like the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what could cause this? The hardware is old and common enough that compatibility shouldn't be an issue. Any idea what else I could change to finally get any Linux to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a video card/driver issue. Try booting with blacklisted nouveau module and/or disable KMS. I'm not sure about Fedora, but usually it's something like adding `modules.blacklist=nouveau` and `nokms` to your kernel command line in your boot loader advanced menu.

You might have more luck with `nvidia` proprietary driver.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably related to the video card, but this is not sure.

I suggest that you start you PC with a diagnostic software booting from a CD, DVD or USB medium. SystemRescueCD is probably a good choice, it's free. Please see the messages generated at the startup and after calling dmesg. Verify carefully the messages and warnings.

Further, there can be a problem related to the BIOS. The BIOS of many PC's has only be tested in relation with MS-Windows. There is a software named FWTS, which can help you to identify possible BIOS problem. There is a bootable version using Ubuntu as base. I recommend you to make this test.